# How to make code object oriented by removing if checks?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a `windows service` which checks for date and send notification remainder to user for a payment for which user has subcribed for a service.

Its a monthly payment service system for which user has to make a payment at the end of the month and for that system sends 2 remainder notification to user :

1) Before N days from deadline if payment not made.

2) Send remainder on deadline if payment not received.

So below are the conditions based on which notifications are send to **User as well as Administrator** : 
[image]

**Code :**

```
public enum PaymentStatusEnum
 {
    Ask_For_Payment = 0,
    Payment_Remainder_Sent = 1,
    Full_Payment_Done = 2,
    Payment_Not_Done = 3,
 }

public class ServicePaymentModel
{   
    public int PaymentId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int PaymentStatus { get; set; }
    public string AdminId { get; set; }
    public int NoOfDaysPassed { get; set; }
    public decimal DueAmount { get; set; }
    public decimal PaymentMade { get; set; }
}

 public void SendNotification()
 {
    int daysBeforeDeadline = 10;
    int deadlineDays = 20;
    var paymentModel = new PaymentModel
    {
        Today = 10/5/2019,
        DaysBeforeDeadline = daysBeforeDeadline,
        DeadlineDays = deadlineDays
    };
    //Get all the payments whose daysBeforeDeadline or deadlineDays condition is met.
    //For eg: If some users subscription started from 1/5/2019 and Todays date is 10/5/2019 then this users will be will be fetched because of daysBeforeDeadline.
    //For eg: If some users subscription started from 20/4/2019 and Todays date is 10/5/2019 then this users will be will be fetched because deadlineDays condition
    List<ServicePaymentModel> payments = MyRepo.GetPayments(paymentModel);
    if (payments != null && payments.Count == 0)
        return;
    UserPayment userPayment = null;
    foreach (var payment in payments)
    {
      try
      {
        if (payment.DueAmount > 0) //Payment not done
        {
            if (paymentModel.DeadlineDays == payment.NoOfDaysPassed
                            && payment.PaymentStatus == (int)PaymentStatusEnum.Payment_Remainder_Sent) // payment not made on deadline
            {
                userPayment = new UserPayment
                {
                    PaymentId = payment.Id,
                    PaymentStatus = (int)PaymentStatusEnum.Payment_Not_Done
                }
                SendNotificationToUser(payment);//method handles email sending and different email template for user
                SendNotificationToAdmin(payment)//method handles email sending and different email template for Admin telling him about which user payment has not been received
            }
            else if (paymentModel.DaysBeforeDeadline == payment.NoOfDaysPassed
                            && payment.PaymentStatus == (int)PaymentStatusEnum.Ask_For_Payment)//payment not done after N days
            {
                userPayment = new UserPayment
                {
                    PaymentId = payment.Id,
                    PaymentStatus = (int)PaymentStatusEnum.Payment_Remainder_Sent
                }
                SendNotificationToUser(payment);//method handles email sending and different email template for user
                SendNotificationToAdmin(payment)//method handles email sending and different email template for Admin telling him about which user payment has not been received
            }
        }
        else if (payment.DueAmount == 0) // payment done
        {   
            userPayment = new UserPayment
            {
              PaymentId = payment.Id,
              PaymentStatus = (int)PaymentStatusEnum.Full_Payment_Done
            }
            if ((paymentModel.DeadlineDays == payment.NoOfDaysPassed
                           && payment.PaymentStatus == (int)PaymentStatusEnum.Ask_For_Payment)// payment made on deadline
            {

                SendNotificationToUser(payment);//method handles email sending and different email template for user along with message and body
                SendNotificationToAdmin(payment)//method handles email sending and different email template for admin along with message and body
            }
            else if (paymentModel.DaysBeforeDeadline == payment.NoOfDaysPassed
                           && payment.PaymentStatus == (int)PaymentStatusEnum.Ask_For_Payment)//payment done before XX days
            {
               SendNotificationToAdmin(payment)//method handles email sending and different email template for admin along with message and body
            }
        }
        PaymentRepo.UpdateUserPaymentStatus(userPayment);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        //do nothing and continue processing other payment             
     }
    }
  }
```

I have seen this [Plural sight video](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/c-sharp-code-more-object-oriented) where **Author - Zoran Horvat** is saying that we can turn almost any If checks to object oriented solution and as you can see my code contains alot of if checks and tomorrow if more `Conditions` are added than this If will grow tremendously creating maintainance night mare.

All my `Conditions and PaymentStatus` are being handled based on If checks but here I am not getting how to turn this if conditions in to object oriented solution and whether it would be really possible or not in this case.

So is it possible to make this code object oriented by removing if checks or any better way to handle this checks?

---

```
public void SendNotificationRefactor2()
{
    int daysBeforeDeadline = 10;
    int deadlineDays = 20;
    var paymentModel = new PaymentModel
    {
        Today = 10 / 5 / 2019,
        DaysBeforeDeadline = daysBeforeDeadline,
        DeadlineDays = deadlineDays
    };
    //Get all the payments whose daysBeforeDeadline or deadlineDays condition is met.
    //For eg: If some users subscription started from 1/5/2019 and Todays date is 10/5/2019 then this users will be will be fetched because of daysBeforeDeadline.
    //For eg: If some users subscription started from 20/4/2019 and Todays date is 10/5/2019 then this users will be will be fetched because deadlineDays condition
    List<ServicePaymentModel> payments = MyRepo.GetPayments(paymentModel);
    if (payments != null && payments.Count == 0)
        return;
    //UserPayment userPayment = null;

    foreach (var payment in payments)
    {
        try
        {
            //  Breaking this out into a method is optional, really, because there's little chance it'll 
            HandlePayment(paymentModel, payment);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //  SWALLOWING EXCEPTIONS IS AN INDESCRIBABLY BAD IDEA. DON'T DO THIS. 
        }
    }
}

protected void HandlePayment(PaymentModel paymentModel, ServicePaymentModel payment)
{
    var userPayment = new UserPayment
    {
        PaymentId = payment.Id
    };

    if (payment.DueAmount > 0) //Payment not done
    {
        if (paymentModel.DeadlineDays == payment.NoOfDaysPassed)
        {
            if (payment.PaymentStatus == (int)PaymentStatusEnum.Payment_Remainder_Sent)
            {
                userPayment.PaymentStatus = (int)PaymentStatusEnum.Payment_Not_Done;
            }
            else if (payment.PaymentStatus == (int)PaymentStatusEnum.Ask_For_Payment)//payment not done after N days
            {
                userPayment.PaymentStatus = (int)PaymentStatusEnum.Payment_Remainder_Sent;
            }

            SendNotificationToUser(payment);//method handles email sending and different email template for user
            SendNotificationToAdmin(payment);//method handles email sending and different email template for Admin telling him about which user payment has not been received
        }
    }
    else if (payment.DueAmount == 0) // payment done
    {
        userPayment.PaymentStatus = (int)PaymentStatusEnum.Full_Payment_Done;

        if (paymentModel.DeadlineDays == payment.NoOfDaysPassed)
        {
            if (payment.PaymentStatus == (int)PaymentStatusEnum.Ask_For_Payment)
            {
                SendNotificationToUser(payment);//method handles email sending and different email template for user along with message and body
                SendNotificationToAdmin(payment);//method handles email sending and different email template for admin along with message and body
            }
            else if (payment.PaymentStatus == (int)PaymentStatusEnum.Ask_For_Payment)
            {
                SendNotificationToAdmin(payment);//method handles email sending and different email template for admin along with message and body
            }
        }
    }

    PaymentRepo.UpdateUserPaymentStatus(userPayment);
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194139/discussion-on-question-by-ilovestackoverflow-how-to-make-code-object-oriented-by).

Answer (score 7):

First off: focus on the goal. The belief that making something more OO makes it better is a belief structure I call "object happiness disorder". Remember, the purpose of OO code is to *lower the costs of large programs worked on by large teams*, by making it very clear what service is provided by a piece of code, what its public interface is, and how it interacts with other components. It's not a general-purpose technique for making small code better.

Your goal should not be to make the program "more OO"; it should be to make it lower cost, so ask yourself "what are the costs associated with this program?"  Where are you spending money, remembering that *your salary is probably most of that money*?

For example:

> We're spending too much time updating the code when business processes change.

If that's the problem then I would make the program more OO, but not by "replace condition with polymorphism". Just because it is polymorphic does not make it OO. What makes it OO is *we have identified fundamental concepts in the business domain and encapsulated those concepts into objects that only have to change when the business process changes*.

The key thing to look at is your extremely helpful diagram that shows:

- What exogenous condition triggers a state change?
- What are the state changes?
- What action is associated with a state change?

So, codify that. Make a base class `EventTrigger`. You've already got a type representing states. Make a class called `EventAction`. Make a class `Condition`. And now what is our process?

```
for each trigger in eventTriggers
    if any trigger condition is met
        execute all trigger actions
```

Now we're down to a single `if` statement, like you wanted. Now you can write one class for each condition, and one class for each action, and triggers tie them together.

If you want to change the action associated with a particular trigger, you change it in one place, not in a mass of spaghetti code.

Also, this technique is amenable to many other improvements. You can easily add logging; logging is just another action. You can make compositions of actions; make an action that takes two actions and runs them both. And so on.

You could even make a configuration document that looks like:

```
TRIGGER PaymentReceivedTrigger HAS CONDITION AskForPayment WITH ACTIONS  SetFullPayment, EmailAdmin
…
```

And now you can set up your whole system based on a config file instead of writing C# code.

But what if that is *not* the problem? What if the problem is:

> We're spending too much time tracking down bugs

Or

> Our performance is bad and we do not know why

Or

> We're completely tied to one database vendor but they are too expensive; how can we lower the cost of switching back ends?

Or any of a million other things?  In those cases, you don't want to waste any time building an OO business process engine; you want to concentrate on the problem that is actually costing you money, and figure out what lowers that cost.

Comment: First of all I am so glad that I got an answer from you for which I have been waiting for so long :) .You are right that I should concentrate more on solving problem but than I think by that way I will end up writing a messed up code as you can see in the question and I will never gonna know what improvements are needed in my code.The goal of question is to get suggestions,feedbacks so that I can learn something out of that and improve my code accordingly .This code is perfectly working fine but it is just that I was not comfortable with this so much of IF statements

Comment: Based on your suggestion regarding a base class called EventTrigger,I am bit confused that What are the things that this class will have as because you can see I have this method MyRepo.GetPayments(paymentModel) which gets list of PAYMENTS and that based on that I check things,perform actions etc...So how do I represent this in EventTrigger,EventAction,Condition . Can you please tell me little bit about this 3 class what exactly they will contain please?