# Optimising code with a lot of "if" statements

Tags: c#, if-statement

I want to optimise this code to reduce the number of `if` statements. Maybe it'd be better to use a lot of classes, and let the classes handle each required action?

It could be fabric pattern? Or is it OK to use 30+ similar `if` statements?

I've tried to make a `Dictionary` with `string` and `object` class. But I couldn't get it to work (or my skills are not good enough)

```
if (node[DATA_CONNECTION_ELEMENT] != null)
{               
    return new DataConnectionPropertyDataBinding(form, node[DATA_CONNECTION_ELEMENT], inputableEntity);
}
else if (node[FORM_PARAMETER_ELEMENT] != null)
{
    return new FormParameterDataBinding(form, node[FORM_PARAMETER_ELEMENT], inputableEntity);
}

// + 30 more else ifs

else if (node[COMMAND_ELEMENT] != null)
{
    return new CommandResultDataBinding(form, node[COMMAND_ELEMENT], inputableEntity);
}
else if (node[CONDITION_ELEMENT] != null)
{
    return new ConditionDataBinding(form, node[CONDITION_ELEMENT], inputableEntity);
}
else if (node[CLIPBOARD_ELEMENT] != null)
{
    return new ClipboardDataBinding(form, node[CLIPBOARD_ELEMENT], inputableEntity);
}
else
{
    return new ConstantDataBinding(form, node);
}
```

Want to make it look something like

```
foreach (var item in allThatShareSomeInterface)
{
    if (item.CanHandle(node.Atributes[0]))
    {
        return item.neededObject();
    }
}
```

Here is the answer. How it really works.

```
        Dictionary<string, Type> allObjects = new Dictionary<string, Type>();
        allObjects.Add(CONDITION_ELEMENT, typeof(ConditionDataBinding));
        allObjects.Add(DATA_TYPE_FORMAT_ELEMENT, typeof(DataTypeFormatDataBinding));
        allObjects.Add(DATA_TYPE_CONVERT_ELEMENT, typeof(DataTypeConvertDataBinding));
        allObjects.Add(FORM_PARAMETER_ELEMENT, typeof(FormParameterDataBinding));
        allObjects.Add(FORM_ELEMENT, typeof(FormPropertyDataBinding));
        allObjects.Add(STRING_ELEMENT, typeof(StringFormatDataBinding));
        allObjects.Add(FORMULA_ELEMENT, typeof(FormulaDataBinding));
        allObjects.Add(COMMAND_ELEMENT, typeof(CommandResultDataBinding));
        // + many


        foreach (var pair in allObjects)
        {
            if (node[pair.Key] != null)
            {
                ConstructorInfo ctor = pair.Value.GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(IWorkflowForm), typeof(XmlNode), typeof(IInputable) });
                return ctor.Invoke(new object[] { form, node[pair.Key], inputableEntity });
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you show your attempt to use a Dictionary?

Comment: And please show an example XML file for this

Comment: dicionary isn't git. I understand it.
`code`_________________________________________________________________________________
var allObj = new Dictionary<string, Type>();
            allObj.Add("bind1", new Class1().GetType());
            allObj.Add("bind2", new Class2().GetType());
            allObj.Add("bind3", new Class3().GetType());

            var needed = allObj["bind1"];
            var g = new needed("params");
@Steve

Comment: Xml contains Name and Type atrubute(like Command, contextMenu). We make parsing of each node accordingly to it's name.
@AdamJachoncki

Comment: This question has been asked twice this morning! see my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56342870/how-to-make-code-object-oriented-by-removing-if-checks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to make this work using reflection. It's probably going to make your code a bit slower though.
It should look something like this (not tested):

```
    var pairs = new Dictionary<string, Type>()
    {
        {
            DATA_CONNECTION_ELEMENT, typeof(DataConnectionPropertyDataBinding)
        },
        {
            FORM_PARAMETER_ELEMENT, typeof(FormParameterDataBinding)
        }
    };

    foreach (var pair in pairs)
    {
        if (node[pair.Key] != null)
        {
            ConstructorInfo ctor = pair.Value.GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(object), typeof(object), typeof(object) });
            return ctor.Invoke(new object[] { form, node[pair.Key], inputableEntity });
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's working!
Big thanks to you!
@Bart van der Drift

Answer (score 0):

If you know what you are doing, and you indeed need that many binding classes, one way to solve that is custom attributes + reflection + runtime code generation. Here’s an example.

```
// Enum for element type. The order matters, it's the order in which input dictionary is tested.
enum eElement
{
    DataConnection,
    FormParameter,
}
// Custom attribute to mark bindings classes with.
class DataBindingAttribute : Attribute
{
    public eElement element;
    public DataBindingAttribute( eElement e ) { element = e; }
}

// Base class for bindings
abstract class BindingBase { }

// Couple test binding classes
[DataBinding( eElement.DataConnection )]
class DataConnectionPropertyDataBinding: BindingBase
{
    public DataConnectionPropertyDataBinding( object data ) { }
}
[DataBinding( eElement.FormParameter )]
class FormParameterDataBinding: BindingBase
{
    public readonly object data;
    public FormParameterDataBinding( object data ) { this.data = data; }
}

// This static class does the magic.
static class BindingsFactory
{
    // Key = eElement from custom attribute, value = function that constructs the binding. This example uses the constructor with single object argument.
    // It's a good idea to use strong types for arguments instead.
    static readonly SortedDictionary<eElement, Func<object, BindingBase>> dictTypes = new SortedDictionary<eElement, Func<object, BindingBase>>();

    static BindingsFactory()
    {
        // Constructor argument types, just a single `object` in this example.
        Type[] constructorArgumentTypes = new Type[ 1 ]
        {
            typeof( object )
        };

        ParameterExpression[] constructorArgumentExpressions = constructorArgumentTypes
            .Select( tp => Expression.Parameter( tp ) )
            .ToArray();

        // Find all types in current assembly
        var ass = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        foreach( Type tp in ass.GetTypes() )
        {
            // Try to get the custom attribute
            var dba = tp.GetCustomAttribute<DataBindingAttribute>();
            if( null == dba )
                continue;

            // Ensure you don't have 2 classes with the same element ID value
            Debug.Assert( !dictTypes.ContainsKey( dba.element ) );
            // Ensure the found type inherits from BindingBase
            Debug.Assert( typeof( BindingBase ).IsAssignableFrom( tp ) );

            // Compile the function that constructs the new binding object
            ConstructorInfo ci = tp.GetConstructor( constructorArgumentTypes );
            Debug.Assert( null != ci );

            // new Binding(...)
            var expNew = Expression.New( ci, constructorArgumentExpressions );
            // (BindingBase)( new Binding( ... ) )
            var expCast = Expression.Convert( expNew, typeof( BindingBase ) ); 
            // Compile into lambda
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, BindingBase>>( expCast, constructorArgumentExpressions );
            // Compile the lambda, and save in the sorted dictionary
            var func = lambda.Compile();
            dictTypes.Add( dba.element, func );
        }
    }

    public static BindingBase tryConstruct( Dictionary<eElement, object> dict )
    {
        foreach( var kvp in dictTypes )
        {
            object arg;
            if( !dict.TryGetValue( kvp.Key, out arg ) )
                continue;
            return kvp.Value( arg );
        }
        return null;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<eElement, object>();
        dict[ eElement.FormParameter ] = 12;
        // This line will construct an instance of FormParameterDataBinding
        var res = BindingsFactory.tryConstruct( dict );
    }
}
```